# Как лучше заменить социальные иконки на сайте?

Tags: css

Верстаю [сайт](http://evolutionnailspanj.brandivo.com/). В шапке и в футере есть социальные иконки ссылки - одна иконка Twitter и вторая Facebook. Мне нужно заменить их на свои картинки как в шапке, так и в футере. Как мне это лучше сделать? Нужно использовать только CSS.

Comment: Я заменил иконки, но теперь они перестали быть ссылками. Как мне их сделать ссылками, чтобы они работали снова?

Comment: сделайте спрайт соц. иконок и через before(after) задайте

Comment: #top #wrap_all .social_bookmarks li a - display: block or display: inline-block

Comment: На эту тему есть хорошая статья с кодами
https://jonsuh.com/blog/social-share-links/